# finding a substring in a list of strings

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list of strings and i have multiple strings added to it .
ex: l1 is a list with three values

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string> 
{
     "issue: there are multiple data errors ",
     "resolution: you can correct the data or /n raise an SR on this issue",
     "rootfix: you need to be contious while entering the data "
};
```

Now i need to check if this list has got all three key strings ie.

```
List<string> keyWords = new List<string> { "isue", "resolution", "rootfix" };
```

I dont think i can use `Contains` operation on this as the above strings are substrings of the list strings.

Please let me know if there is any function available /logic.

If all the three substrings are there in the list then i need to return boolian

Comment: You can use `StartsWith()`-> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What did you try ? Could you provide us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Are the three examples you give _different_ strings in the same `List<string>`?

Comment: i am extracting the onscreen text  and adding it to the list .I have to stop extracting action once my list has got strings with all three key words . for that i have to check for these key works in the list and continue in the loop

Comment: What's wrong with using `Contains`? You can just use it in a loop

Comment: Or use `List<T>.Any()`

Comment: @Martin I have given 3 different strings in the list example and all three strings has got 3 different  key substrings which i have to check

Comment: @Aousafrashid contains needs full string to check . but i have to check with only substrings and there are multiple substrings

Comment: "I dont think i can use contains operation" you can but not the `IEnumerable.Contains` method but the `String.Contains` method

Comment: @Abhishek you make no sense. Please provide a full example of what needs to happen. With what you have posted and said that contains is Invalid. You need the StartsWith(). Now please edit your post and show us clearly when you need to return false or true.

Comment: if one of the answers helped you to solve your problem, please mark it as accepted. If you don't know how to do it, [here is a helpful post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether [All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.8) keywords match in [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) item of your wordset that might [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8) your key word

```
List<string> keyWords = new List<string>{"issue","resolution","rootfix"};

List<string> wordSet = new List<string>{"issue: there are multiple data errors ", "resolution: you can correct the data or /n raise an SR on this issue", "rootfix: you need to be contious while entering the data "};

bool result = keyWords.All(x => wordSet.Any(w => w.Contains(x)));
```

For a human being it is probably easier to read from inside out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on whether your example is showing three *separate* strings in your `List<string>`, or whether they are *one single string*.

In the first case, three separate strings in a `List<string>`, you could use something like:

```
bool isInList = l1.Any(x => x.StartsWith("issue")) &&
                l1.Any(x => x.StartsWith("resolution")) &&
                l1.Any(x => x.StartsWith("rootfix"));
```

This will return `true` if all of the matching strings are found in `l1`.

If it is the second case, and a single string containing the values as you described them:

```
string l1 = "{\"issue: there are multiple data errors \", \"resolution: you can correct the data or /n raise an SR on this issue\", \"rootfix: you need to be contious while entering the data \"}";
bool isInString = l1.Contains("\"issue") &&
                  l1.Contains("\"resolution") &&
                  l1.Contains("\"rootfix"))
```

This will return `true` where all three names appear in the same string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var data = new []{"issue: there are multiple data errors ", "resolution: you can correct the data or /n raise an SR on this issue", "rootfix: you need to be contious while entering the data "};

bool flag = (
    data.Any(d => d.StartsWith("issue:")) &&
    data.Any(d => d.StartsWith("resolution:")) &&
    data.Any(d => d.StartsWith("rootfix:"))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use LINQ? Just using Where() and String.StartsWith() you can achieve this!

```
        var list = new List<string> {
            "issue: test1",
            "resolution: test2",
            "rootfix: test3"
        };

        var issues = list.Where(x => x.StartsWith("issue"));

        foreach(var i in issues) {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

OUTPUT: "issue: test1"